# What does InvalidCobrandConversationCredentialsExceptionFault means?

Tags: yodlee

I'm getting `InvalidCobrandConversationCredentialsExceptionFault` exception when trying to login a user. What is the reason for this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InvalidCobrandConversationCredentialsExceptionFault – is usually because 120 mins or more have lapsed since the last time CobrandContext was created/renewed. We suggest that clients should renew the cobrand context every 90 mins(to be on safe side) or so… OR renew every time this exceptions comes.

From Yodlee Aggregation SDK Quick Reference Guide:

Yodlee suggests making a CobrantContext singleton object that is thread safe. A call is made to "getCobrandContext" method that is synchronized and either creates a new cobrand context (this operation is thread safe since the method is synchronized) or returns the existing object. Since all Yodlee interaction requires a Cobrand Context, it is guaranteed that this will always be every threads first interaction with Yodlee and guarantee Axis is initialized in a thread-safe model.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Prashant

Answer (score 0):

Likely it means you are not passing a valid cobrand credential to the login call.  Before you can make any calls, you need to request a cobrand session id.  You do this by calling the `coblogin` (REST API) call with your assigned cobrand (looks like sbCob and your password.  This returns a cobrand session Id which is then required for all subsequent calls.  You need to pass this as the `cobSessionToken` param when making the login call ([REST login API](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/REST_API_Reference/login))

Comment: We defenitely using correct cobrand credentials and also we are using SOAP API.